# Could not create java virtual machine

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When i try to open eclipse, it displayes this errorr: "Could not create java virtual machine" . I already tried all solution said on internet or stackowerflow, but didnt work for me. Please help me. How can i solve that. ( win 10 64bit)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check heap size specified in vm argument while starting.My guess is your jvm is pointing jdk 32 bit and in your heap you have mentioned higher value.That is the main reason for it.

check in `eclipse.ini` all value are correct or not

```
-vm
 C:/java/bin/javaw.exe
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms40m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xverify:none
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
-Xmx1200m
```

Comment: Heap size is 512 and jdk is 64

Comment: can you please provide your eclipse.ini file

Comment: What do you mean provide? What do you want me to do?